# How do i add an email input to my website without creating a main form

Tags: html, css

[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm34R.png)

I want to make something like the above image.
I've tried using the form tag and then input and label but it doesn't look the same. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Here's one for you

```css
form {
  background: black;
  padding: 20px;
}

.FieldGroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 550px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

input {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: purple;
  opacity: 1;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

button:active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="FieldGroup">
    <input type="email" id="fields-form-insights-e-mail" class="fui-input Form-field Form-field--input" name="fields[eMail]" placeholder="Email address" autocomplete="email" required="" data-fui-id="form-insights-e-mail" data-fui-message="" aria-required="true">
    <button type="submit" class="Button Button--primary Button--insights FieldGroup-append">
                            Subscribe
                        </button>
  </div>
</form>
```